# NESTED JSON : Key extraction based on value in JSON using JSON path /GSON

Tags: json, gson, parent-child, jsonpath

I have a nested JSON as shown below. I would like to extract the key e.g. `PersonB` based on a search on the value of it e.g. `Age ==60`. Is JSON the right data Structure to achieve something like this?. I have tried using JSONpath. But could not come up with a query to extract something like this.

```
{
   "PersonA":{
      "shortnames":[
         "Bravo",
         "Delta"
      ],
      "Name":"Person 123",
      "Age":"15",
      "Maritial Status":"Single",
      "Work Experience":"O",
      "ID":291
   }   "PersonB":{
      "shortnames":[
         "Alpha",
         "Tango"
      ],
      "Name":"Person 234",
      "Age":"60",
      "Maritial Status":"Married",
      "Work Exxperience":"2O",
      "ID":292
   }
}
```

Any pointers as to how such a query would look like?

Comment: Just wondering whether the below answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to get the key where Age is '60'.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String jsonString = "{\"PersonA\": {\"shortnames\": [\"Bravo\",\"Delta\"],\"Name\": \"Person 123\",\"Age\": \"15\",\"Maritial Status\": \"Single\",\"Work Experience\": \"O\",\"ID\": 291},\"PersonB\": {\"shortnames\": [\"Alpha\",\"Tango\"],\"Name\": \"Person 234\",\"Age\": \"60\",\"Maritial Status\": \"Married\",\"Work Exxperience\": \"2O\",\"ID\": 292},\"PersonC\": {\"shortnames\": [\"Alpha\",\"Tango\"],\"Name\": \"Person 234\",\"Maritial Status\": \"Married\",\"Work Exxperience\": \"2O\",\"ID\": 292}}";           
        Gson gson = new Gson();         
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class);            

        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonEntry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            if (jsonEntry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("Age") != null ) {
                if (jsonEntry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("Age").getAsString().equals("60")) {
                    System.out.println(jsonEntry.getKey());
                    System.out.println(jsonEntry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Output:-**

```
PersonB
{"shortnames":["Alpha","Tango"],"Name":"Person 234","Age":"60","Maritial Status":"Married","Work Exxperience":"2O","ID":292}
```